# How do I turn a mesh into a normal?

Tags: normal-map

So I want to create an item for a game that I play, and the game uses what appears to be a normal map to generate the 3d texture, and then applies a texture over that.
I have a model of a crown that I would like to add into the game, and to do that I need a normal map of the entire mesh. **So my question is**, *how do I turn an entire mesh into a normal map*.

This is an example of a helmet in the game (both links are links to pictures):

The game files are .dds, but I changed them to .jpeg so they can be viewed.

[helmet texture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f4_3EZQON-ipnS_C2zbOLylJui4R9Zpb)

[helmet normal map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p9mxYEUdJCU9ioaVVWlrca-uUDgFz1zq)

Thanks a lot,

Lance

Comment: You can bake a normal map, but you still need a 3D model that it's applied to (it's not a replacement for the model). Commonly you have a high poly mesh that contains geometric details that you want to apply to a low poly using a normal map making it look like it had the geometric details, but it's just a texture.

Comment: I already take into account that the DDS file contains textures of different dimensions and starting with that of 512x512 px and decreases with values divisible by 2?

Comment: and how do you plan to generate the dds file?, although I combined the jpg file it retains the DDS format information, I have not really addressed the issue of creating dds files, on the other hand there is the fact that I need to model the 3d object and put it in your game and there is also the programming part if it is required to add it to your game